# WaitForSingleObject called on semaphore fails with last error 183 (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, semaphore

I am trying to write a class BlockingQueue for producer-consumer style tasks. I'm using WinAPI, but i have a problem with `WaitForSingleObject`. When i call it on semaphore with value 0, instead of falling asleep it returns -1 (WAIT_FAILED) and `GetLastError()` gives 183 (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS). That makes me no sense, so i think i must be doing something terribly wrong. The method, where appears the problem looks this way:

```
template<typename elem_t>
elem_t BlockingQueue<elem_t>::pop() {

    WaitForSingleObject(_used_sem, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(_mutex, INFINITE);
    uint first = _first;
    if (++_first == _length)
        _first = 0;
    _count--;
    ReleaseMutex(_mutex);
    ReleaseSemaphore(_free_sem, 1, NULL);
    return _data[first];

}
```

both semaphores and the mutex are initialized in the constructor:

```
template<typename elem_t>
BlockingQueue<elem_t>::BlockingQueue(uint length) {

    _data = new elem_t [length];
    _length = length;
    _count  =  0;
    _first  =  0;
    _last   = -1;
    _mutex    = CreateMutex(NULL, false, NULL);
    _free_sem = CreateSemaphore(NULL, _length, INFINITE, NULL);
    _used_sem = CreateSemaphore(NULL, _count,  INFINITE, NULL);

}
```

Any ideas why i'm getting such strange error?

EDIT: Error 183 was due to wrong error checking, because it got overwritten by another error before calling GetLastError(). After correcting it, it's just 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE), much more meaningful.

Comment: Error checking is very often fumbled.  Posting code that does no checking at all does not help us help you.

Comment: (1) Show the code that uses these functions. (2) Show code that's actually checking the return value of `WaitForSingleObject` and calling `GetLastError`.

Comment: Ah yes, i get your point. You are right, GetLastError was called too late, when the error was already overwritten by something else, now i have 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)

Comment: There's really no point in asking for help when we cannot see the code. Please show code with some error checking. Again, it's likely that you got the error checking wrong. We cannot tell you what you did wrong until you show code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not checking the return value of CreateSemaphore. It is likely that it is failing in this case or if it is succeeding it is creating a "impossible" semaphore. This is due to your use of `INFINITE` for the maximum count parameter. The maximum count argument is a signed long, INFINITE is intended for use with unsigned millisecond duration, and if you interpret as a signed LONG value, you will end up with -1. The documentation states the maximum count value must be above 0. Use LONG_MAX instead of INFINITE when creating your semaphores.

Comment: Yes, this is it! INFINITE was unsigned, so it was -1 as signed. Replacing it with LONG_MAX solved the problem.